# Why neural network's output is not sensitive to input scale?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Recently, I read a paper about RNN and CNN. It said that due to the non-linear nature of the Convolutional and Recurrent components, one major drawback of the neural network model
is that the scale of outputs is not sensitive to the scale of inputs. I am quite confused why it happens. Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot.

Paper source: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.07015

Comment: Which paper? Can you edit your post to include a complete citation and link?

Comment: I have added paper link. Thanks